# createNormalSurfaceLockedFailed Android

Tags: java, android

When I exit and reopen my application, it immediately kills itself off, stating in the logcat:

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it would be running out of resources, when there is pretty much nothing that it does when resuming the application, other than set a few variables. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, I had been changing the SurfaceView's pixel format in the restart() method.